# Scala: How to properly reorder a list?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a Scala List of objects. Each object is a case class comprised of an integer index and a string.

```
case class Item(index: Integer, name: String)
```

I have this list populated with, say, five items. Each item has a numeric index and some value in the string.

```
List(Item(0, "foo"), Item(1, "bar"), Item(2, "baz"), Item(3, "foobie"), Item(4, "blech"))
```

I have decided that I'd like the Item in "slot 3" to be in "slot 1." So what I want to do is not only set the index of the item in slot 3 to be 1, but I also want to physically reorder the List as well by pushing everything down. In other words, "promote" an Item later-on in the list closer to the beginning. I would end up with:

```
List(Item(0, "foo"), Item(1, "foobie"), Item(2, "bar"), Item(3, "baz"), Item(4, "blech"))
```

Sure, I can do this with an array and a var in the usual ways, but if I want to use an immutable list and simply create a new one, is there a nice, functional syntax for map that might help me do this? Or is there some kind of functional way to do this properly?

Comment: Why do you keep the index in Item and not just the name? (it would then be rather easier)

Comment: Whereas that's a fine question, it's not relevant to asking how to reorder. And presume that I need to keep the index thusly, which is why I have it there. I need to reorder the list AND modify the field while doing it. The reasoning here is that each Item may be used outside of its context in the List, and the consumer needs to know the index. Thus, the Item must know.

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler It's helpful to construct an example that's not so trivially resolved rather than telling someone you don't like their approach, because real constraints will help inform solutions that actually apply for your real-world problem. Given the information you provide, I'd just do `reorder(myList.map(_.name)).zipWithIndex.map(pair => Item(pair._2, pair._1)`, where reorder is some function of type `List[String] => List[String]` implementing the logic you didn't specify.

Comment: I'm not clear. There is no other logic. The input is a list, and two integers. The first integer is the slot of the list entry I want to move, and the second integer is the slot I want it to be in. The structure of Item is exactly how I want it, and the requirement to change the index parameter was specified. What have I left out? I simply explained WHY I outlined it the way I did. But as far as I can tell, the real constraints are all there in the original question, no?

Comment: @ChristopherAmbler, the question is why you want the Items to hold the index if the index values are always the position of the Item in the list. It's redundant,and means we have to re-create Items when they move, rather than just moving existing Items around. Items can know their position in the list without storing it as a member - a 'index` method could just look itself up in the list.

Comment: Gotcha. The reason is that an Item may be extracted from the list and handed to a JSon serializer in Java code that needs to send the index as part of its response, when sending back a single Item. Yes, ugly. No, not my code. I'm handed the Items as such and need to return an item as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here you go, although I don't like it much.

From your comment, the index values can have gaps and so are not the position in the list. So we can assume nothing much about them so this just extracts them (and the Strings), manipulates the list of Strings, then builds Items from the list of indexes and resultant list of Strings.

```
case class Item(index: Integer, name: String)
val xs = List(Item(0, "foo"), Item(1, "bar"), Item(2, "baz"), Item(3, "foobie"), Item(4, "blech"))

def move(xs: List[Item], src:Int, dst:Int) = {
    val strings = xs.map(_.name)
    val indices = xs.map(_.index)
    val (prefix, d::rest) = strings splitAt(dst)
    val (middle, s::suffix) = rest splitAt(src-dst-1)
    (indices zip (prefix ++ List(s) ++ List(d) ++ middle ++ suffix))
       map  {case (i, s) => Item (i, s)}
}
move (xs, 3, 1)
//> res0: List[lists.lists2.Item] = List(Item(0,foo), Item(1,foobie), 
                                         Item(2,bar), Item(3,baz), Item(4,blech))
```

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, the index in Item might have gaps. So this would accommodate for that.

Comment: OK. So given Items are immutable, we'll have to recreate all Items between src and dst anyway. So this creates a few more than necessary but is reasonably concise